# CrystalClear Report Error [219] [Pool Manager] Cannot load specified driver: null null

Tags: java, jdbc, crystal-reports

We are able to run crystal reports fine when java application is launch from eclipse IDE.

However when it is already deployed, the following occurs when running the reports.

```
[CC,TRACE] Report Error [225] The DB connection to "jdbc:inetora:cs-v-oracx4sd1.champ.aero:1521:CX4SD111?logging=true" failed (see crystalclear.properties): [Pool Manager] Cannot load specified driver: null null.
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.y(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.q(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.run(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.zy.h$a.run(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE] Caused by: Report Error [219] [Pool Manager] Cannot load specified driver: null null
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.Engine.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.Engine.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.Engine.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.Engine.throwException(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.zy.a.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  ... 5 more
[CC,TRACE] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
[CC,TRACE]  at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
[CC,TRACE]  ... 7 more
[CC,TRACE] caused by: Report Error [219] [Pool Manager] Cannot load specified driver: null null
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.Engine.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.Engine.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.Engine.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.Engine.throwException(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.zy.a.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.y(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.q(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.run(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.zy.h$a.run(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
[CC,TRACE]  at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
[CC,TRACE]  ... 7 more
[CC,TRACE] caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
[CC,TRACE]  at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.zy.a.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.a(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.y(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.q(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.b1.run(Unknown Source)
[CC,TRACE]  at com.inet.report.zy.h$a.run(Unknown Source)
```

The following jars exists and are present in the classpath
crystalclear-8.x.jar
oranxo-3.12.jar

Is anyone familiar with the above error?

```
Cannot load specified driver: null null
```

How about the variables used to display the null null in the error?
I think will give us some clue on the problem but I have no idea.
We didn't had this error from the previous version of our app.
All parameters defined were same as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a classpath error.
Oranxo driver is loaded by the app but failed to load it to the report engine.